# How to deal with Dynamic Programming problems where the current actions allowed depends on a previously done action?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am beginning to solve DP problems by tabulation, and I am curious as to how to deal with such questions. For example, these type of questions: https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_c, http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=574, and also https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1097. Normally in the top down version of such problems, a flag is passed down to the next function call so the program knows not to repeat the same action, for example like passing a flag denoting that activity 0 was previously chosen (Vacation question), passing a flag denoting that the water has already been drank (Fruit Feast question), passing a flag denoting whose turn it is (Removal Game question), but how is this done in the bottom up version? I am not looking for a solution to these problems as I have already done them, but instead sort of a general idea to deal with such problems in a bottom up manner where an action depends on the previous actions done or where an action can only be done once. Thank you in advance.

**For those who cannot access the links:**

**Link 1**:
Problem Statement

Taro's summer vacation starts tomorrow, and he has decided to make plans for it now.
The vacation consists of N days. For each i (1≤i≤N), Taro will choose one of the following activities and do it on the i-th day:
A: Swim in the sea. Gain a i points of happiness. B: Catch bugs in the mountains. Gain b i points of happiness.
C: Do homework at home. Gain c i points of happiness.
As Taro gets bored easily, he cannot do the same activities for two or more consecutive days. Find the maximum possible total points of happiness that Taro gains.

Constraints

All values in input are integers.
1≤N≤10
5

1≤a
i
​
,b
i
​
,c
i
​
≤10
4

**Link 2**: Problem Statement

Bessie has broken into Farmer John's house again! She has discovered a pile of lemons and a pile of oranges in the kitchen (effectively an unlimited number of each), and she is determined to eat as much as possible.
Bessie has a maximum fullness of T (1≤T≤5,000,000). Eating an orange increases her fullness by A, and eating a lemon increases her fullness by B (1≤A,B≤T). Additionally, if she wants, Bessie can drink water at most one time, which will instantly decrease her fullness by half (and will round down).

Help Bessie determine the maximum fullness she can achieve!

**Link 3** : Problem Statement

There is a list of n numbers and two players who move alternately. On each move, a player removes either the first or last number from the list, and their score increases by that number. Both players try to maximize their scores.
What is the maximum possible score for the first player when both players play optimally?

Constraints:

1≤n≤5000

−10^9≤xi≤10^9

Comment: Would you consider summarizing those three problems inside your post, rather than linking to external websites? Also note the links are not clickable.

Comment: @Stef Hello, I have provided the problem statements and also made the links clickable. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Next time, please ask one question only.

Answer (score 0):

(For problems 2 and 3 I read solutions posted online and describe my understanding and code versions below. For problem 1, I did not look up a solution online.)

For problem 1 (Taro's summer vacation), we have the state at the end of activities as `dp[i] = [a, b, c]`, where each element of the tuple, `[a, b, c]`, indicates the most points of happiness if Taro performs that activity on the `i`th day. Since we are not allowed two consecutive days of the same activity, the state of each day as activity X is dependent on the other two activities the day before.

```
dp[0] = [A[0], B[0], C[0]]
dp[i][0] = A[i] + max(dp[i-1][1], dp[i-1][2])
dp[i][1] = B[i] + max(dp[i-1][0], dp[i-1][2])
dp[i][2] = C[i] + max(dp[i-1][0], dp[i-1][1])
```

```js
function f(ABC){
  const n = ABC.length;
  const dp = [];
  
  dp[0] = ABC[0];
  
  for (let i=1; i<n; i++){
    dp[i] = [0, 0, 0];
    dp[i][0] = ABC[i][0] + Math.max(dp[i-1][1], dp[i-1][2]);
    dp[i][1] = ABC[i][1] + Math.max(dp[i-1][0], dp[i-1][2]);
    dp[i][2] = ABC[i][2] + Math.max(dp[i-1][0], dp[i-1][1]);
  }

  return Math.max(dp[n-1][0], dp[n-1][1], dp[n-1][2])
}

var ABC = [
  [10, 40, 70],
  [20, 50, 80],
  [30, 60, 90]
];

for (row of ABC)
  console.log(String(row));
  
console.log(f(ABC));
```

---

For problem 2 (Bessie's fullness), our dp state is two dimensional booleans, one for before halving the fullness and one for after, `dp[i] = [before, after]`. `dp[i][0]` (before halving the fullness) is achievable if we can arrive at it by having added either A or B. `dp[i/2][1]` (after halving the fullness) is achievable if `dp[i][0]` was achievable.

```
dp[0] = [true, true]
dp[i][0] = dp[i - A][0] OR dp[i - B][0]
dp[i/2][1] = dp[i][0]
```

Perform another run for after the fullness is halved.

```
dp[i][1] = dp[i - A][1] OR dp[i - B][1]
```

```js
function f(T, A, B){
  const dp = [];
  
  dp[0] = [true, true];
  
  for (let i=1; i<=T; i++){
    dp[i] = [false, false];
    dp[i][0] ||= i - A >= 0 && dp[i - A][0];
    dp[i][0] ||= i - B >= 0 && dp[i - B][0];
    dp[Math.floor(i/2)][1] = dp[i][0];
  }

  for (let i=0; i<=T; i++){
    dp[i][1] ||= i - A >= 0 && dp[i - A][1];
    dp[i][1] ||= i - B >= 0 && dp[i - B][1];
  }

  for (let i=T; i>=0; i--)
    if (dp[i][1])
      return i;
}

var T = 8;
var A = 5;
var B = 6;

console.log(String([T, A, B]));
console.log(f(T, A, B));
```

---

For problem 3 (maximise score), player 1 wants to maximise `score_1 - score_2` and player 2 wants to minimise `score_1 - score_2`. Our dp state for the current interval, `dp[left][right]` describes `score_1 - score_2`. `dp[left][right]` when `left` equals `right` is the score player 1 gets for taking that single element:

```
dp[i][i] = A[i]
```

Otherwise, we consider what happens if player 1 takes each side.

If player 1 takes `A[l]`, we are left with the interval `dp[l + 1][r]`, which is the score achivable by player 2 since it's their turn. So `score_1 - score_2` will be:

```
A[l] - dp[l + 1][r]
```

And if player 1 takes `A[r]`, the score player 2 will achieve is `dp[l][r - 1]`, and `score_1 - score_2` will be:

```
A[r] - dp[l][r - 1]
```

Of course, player 1 would like the maximum of these two options:

```
dp[l][r] = max(A[l] - dp[l + 1][r], A[r] - dp[l][r - 1])
```

```js
function f(A){
  const n = A.length;
  const dp = [];
  let total = 0;

  for (let i=0; i<n; i++){
    dp[i] = new Array(n).fill(0);
    dp[i][i] = A[i];
    total += A[i];
  }

  for (let l=n-2; l>=0; l--)
    for (let r=l+1; r<n; r++)
      dp[l][r] = Math.max(A[l] - dp[l + 1][r], A[r] - dp[l][r - 1]);
  
  // total + difference
  // = (score_1 + score_2) + (score_1 - score_2)
  // = score_1 + score_1
  // return (score_1 + score_1) / 2
  return (total + dp[0][n-1]) / 2;
}

var A = [4, 5, 1, 3];

console.log(String(A));
console.log(f(A));
```